# How to create a new folder and write new logs there when the new month arrives?

Tags: node.js

There are magazines that are created every day. How to do sure that when the new month arrives, a folder is created and all the logs are written there. And so every time a new month comes.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = [
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December"
    ];
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    return day + '_' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '_' + year;
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var hours = time.getHours();
    var minutes = time.getMinutes();
    var seconds = time.getSeconds();
    return hours + '_' + minutes + '_' + seconds;
}

var ws = fs.createWriteStream(`./logs/file-${formatDate(new Date())}-${formatTime(new Date())}.log`, {
    'flags': 'w',
    'encoding': 'utf8'
});

process.stdout.wr = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.er = process.stderr.write;

process.stdout.write = function (mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.wr(mes, c);
};

process.stderr.write = function (mes, c) {
    ws.write(mes + '\r\n');
    process.stdout.er(mes, c);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to execute a function every specific time i can recommend you the npm package later.js. If you have problems with your code, please write your question for other users better